# Getting Error "You need to be root to perform this command" ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I am running below playbook. which will login to the server using ec2-user but mysql-java-connector will be installed, my test1 user.

```
---
- hosts: cluster
  become: yes
  remote_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
  - name: Create test1 User
      user:
        name: test1
        password: '$6$jQX0JQzf8GB$NI/Pv1rMLyxWYaFCGNsbrun3sfn5bXSzg89Ip.ga2yf3n7hhrjiPsEo5IChIA7X8xVxnuZzm2sWA7IRM6qZOR0'
        state: present
        shell: /bin/bash       # Defaults to /bin/bash
        system: no             # Defaults to no
        createhome: yes        # Defaults to yes
        home: /home/test1
  - name: Add users to sudoers
      lineinfile:
        dest : /etc/sudoers
        state: present
        line: 'test1  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL'
  - name: Install mysql java connector
      become_user: test1
      become_method: sudo
      yum: name=mysql-connector-java state=present
```

Gets below error:

```
fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.211]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "You need to be root to perform this command.\n", "rc": 1, "results": [""]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Same error, you should include become and become_user. In some cases add become method. [More](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become)

```
- hosts: somehost
  name: Install something 
  become: yes
  remote_user: yourname
```

> become
>
> set to yes to activate privilege escalation.
>
> become_user
>
> set to user with desired privileges — the user you become, NOT the user you login as. Does NOT imply become: yes, to allow it to be set
> at host level. Default value is root.

Comment: for more informations, please visit : [Ansible docs : become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/become.html)

Answer (score -1):

Add `ansible_user=Your-User` and `ansible_become=true` in `/etc/ansible/hosts` file to remove this error:

> You need to be root to perform this command

Answer (score -2):

Replace `become_user: test1` to `become_user: root` (or delete this line, because `become_user` is `root` by default).

Please read [Understanding privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) for more information.

Comment: i want to install with test1 user which is having sudo permission. If i use become_user: root mean i am installing it through root user.  same way like most user install and run apache with apache user instead of root.

Comment: If only `test` user have full `sudo` permission, then use `remote_user: test` instead of `remote_user: ec2-user`. Anyway, `yum` works from `root` user only.

To run your service from non-root, you should reconfigure your service after installation. But there are no service start in your example, only installation. Installation with `yum` works only from `root` user.